# Does the very meaning of the word Catholic indicate how the church came about?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, pagan

Catholic

> adjective
>   1.
>   broad or wide-ranging in tastes, interests, or the like; having sympathies with all; broad-minded; liberal.    http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/catholic

Does this definition fit the narrative that the Roman Catholic Church was formed by amalgamating old pagan beliefs and new Christian beliefs in an attempt for the church to unify the citizens of Rome?
Does this explain the similarities between Greco-Roman pre-Christian religion and the "new" Catholic Church?
For example incorporating the use of the cross into Christian worship . The New Catholic Encyclopedia admits: “The cross is found in both pre-Christian and non-Christian cultures.” Various other authorities have linked the cross with nature worship and pagan sex rites.

Comment: No, the word was used as a way of describing the "universal church" - that is all Christians.  It was only much later that it became a proper noun.  (I may offer a fuller answer later.)

Comment: And, what similarities in particular?

Comment: Your narrative of the formation of the Catholic church is entirely incorrect, so it's not possible for the name to reflect it. Where did you get that description from?

Comment: I agree with @DJClayworth that this was not how the Christian Church formed. Notice that this word came into use when we would think it better to say "Christian Church". This is because early Christianity was divided between what we would now call Catholic+Orthodox and Gnostic branches. The word 'Catholic' came into use to claim universality for the Catholic+Orthodox branch, against the splintered Gnostic Christians.

Comment: @Pam where is your evidence of that?

Comment: @Pam Interestingly, there doesn't seem to have been a question asked about the Church's response to claims such as those in that book. That would be a good question to ask.

Comment: @Pam The Christian Church from the very beginning absorbed Cynic, Platonic, Neoplatonic and Aristotlean concepts, but none of this (nor anything done by Constantine) had anything to do with the use of the word 'Catholic'.

Comment: @dickharfiekd if Catholic means universal or liberal or wide ranging does that not describe precisely what your comment indicates all inclusive one size fits all? Thus Roman Catholic Church would be the Roman universal unified all inclusive church?

Comment: @Pam I did not DV your question, merely pointed out that it seems to be based on incorrect premises. If others agree, these incorrect premises are more likely the reason for DVs. I rarely DV, but would be just as likely to DV a Catholic Q or A as, say, an LDS one.

Comment: You would get just as many downvotes if you posted a question like this about the Latter-day Saints.

Answer (score 3):

Catholic-  The word comes from the Greek "katholikós"  which best traslates in english to >"according to the whole"

The earliest recorded evidence of the use of the term "Catholic Church" is the Letter to the Smyrnaeans that Ignatius of Antioch wrote in about 107 to Christians in Smyrna. Exhorting Christians to remain closely united with their bishop, he wrote:

> "Wherever the bishop shall appear, there let the multitude [of the people] also be; even as, wherever Jesus Christ is, there is the Catholic Church."
> [Source (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_term_%22Catholic%22)

Now lets look at wether Saint Ignatius of Antioch was indeed a supporter of paganism and liberalism in the Church.

A Student of the Apostle John himself, while en route to Rome, where he met his martyrdom by being fed to wild beasts, he wrote a series of letters which have been preserved as an example of very early Christian theology. Important topics addressed in these letters include ecclesiology, the sacraments, and the role of bishops.

Here is one that sounds very Catholic, he must have learned it from the Apostle John himself perhaps with the term katholikós as well.

> The Epistle of Ignatius to the Smyrnaeans (written 98-117 AD)
>
> "They abstain from the Eucharist and from prayer, because they confess not the Eucharist to be the flesh of our Saviour Jesus Christ, which suffered for our sins, and which the Father, of His goodness, raised up again. Those, therefore, who speak against this gift of God, incur death in the midst of their disputes. But it were better for them to treat it with respect, that they also might rise again. It is fitting, therefore, that you should keep aloof from such persons, and not to speak of them either in private or in public, but to give heed to the prophets, and above all, to the Gospel, in which the passion [of Christ] has been revealed to us, and the resurrection has been fully proved. But avoid all divisions, as the beginning of evils."

There is a traditon going back to the 1st century that Ignatius was actually one of the Children who was held by Christ himself.  He chose the name Theophorus (God Bearer) For that reason.  Makes me wonder if he remebered being held by the Creator of the world as a child.

There are many ways you can learn about the Church founded by Christ, The Church Fathers, the men who faithfully preserved the Scriptures and the faith, however, if you come into the conversation with Pre-concieved notions provided by staunch anti-Catholics like Dave Hunt and many others seeing the truth will be difficult.

Comment: check this out and comment back to me your thoughts http://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/1978768

Comment: @Pam  I find nothing offensive about this article.

Comment: Cf. [Catholic | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03449a.htm). And subsequently I have a problem with the article because of the word "holy" as in the holy [Catholic] Church which preceeded the word "Catholic" by a few centuries in reference to the Church. The underpinnings of the article is that "all are welcome" without a change of behaviour, while the holy Catholic Church, like Israel, are a "holy" people, i.e., a people set apart.